# Typescript: declare a type in .d.ts file and use it without importing

Tags: typescript

I want to know what is the right way to use types or interfaces without directly importing them (if that's an ok idea).

Currently I have this code:

```
import { TCollection } from "../__types__";

function doSomething(collection: TCollection) {
  // ...
}
```

So to get rid of an `import` statement I have tried to replace `typeRoots` inside of `tsconfig.json` with this value:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["./src/__types__/types.d.ts", "./node_modules/@types"],
  }
}
```

And declared a type in `./src/__types__/types.d.ts`:

```
declare type TCollection = {
  ...
};
```

But still having an error:

```
function doSomething(collection: TCollection) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                 Cannot find name 'TCollection'.ts(2304)
}
```

Did I made a mistake or is it an IDE bug or something? Thanks

Comment: Does it work, if you change your typeroots to:     "typeRoots": ["./src/__types__", "./node_modules/@types"],?

Comment: nope, still the same

Answer (score 3):

you can define the types on the global scope:

```js
// global-types.d.ts
import { Something } from "somewhere";

declare global {
  interface TCollection {
    ...
  }
}
```

if you do not need to import anything in your `global-types.d.ts` you can just declare the interface directly:

```js
// global-types.d.ts
import { Something } from "somewhere";

interface TCollection {
  ...
}
```

no need for any tsconfig changes